# Fixing "The property order is not recognised by Google for an object of type Product" without changing core code in PrestaShop

Tags: prestashop, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I use PrestaShop and I don’t want to change any of the core code. The core code allows for a price in Schema.org. My prices have a low price and discount amount also. Low price is from aggregate offer and discount is from order.

I get the error below:

> The property `order` is not recognised by Google for an object of type `Product`

```html
<link itemprop="discount" itemscope href="http://schema.org/Order"/>
```

&

```html
<link itemprop="highPrice" itemscope href="http://schema.org/AggregateOffer"/>
```

```html
<p class="our_price_display" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"><link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock"/><span id="our_price_display" itemprop="price">€ 0.75</span>&nbsp;<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR" /></p><p id="reduction_percent" ><span id="reduction_percent_display" ><link itemprop="discount" itemscope href="http://schema.org/Order"/>25% Off </span>
</p><p id="reduction_amount" ><span id="reduction_amount_display">
</span></p><p id="old_price"><span id="old_price_display">
<link itemprop="highPrice" itemscope href="http://schema.org/AggregateOffer"/> € 1.00</span>
```

Comment: Where do you get this error? And do you get this error with the posted code snippet? (because it doesn’t contain any `order` property …)

Comment: hi @unor, i tested at webmasters tools and got this error. where in the code would i put in the order property? thank you, trev

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use the `discount` from **Order** for a **Product** (since a product is not an order...) is what Google is saying. Like the [schema.org spec for Order](http://schema.org/Order) says:

> An order is a confirmation of a transaction (a receipt), which can contain multiple line items, each represented by an Offer that has been accepted by the customer.

I'm not aware of any other property like "discount" in Schema, maybe http://schema.org/PriceSpecification is sort of that direction?

Comment: hey thanks for that @defuzed , so if discount is from an order is there a way to put in the code : order, then discount? as my products have discounts on them. so ideally, i can put in from schema / order/ discount. i know its not technically correct but my products have discounts and i would like to show them through schema. thanks again.